# create launch images for uitableview to support older ios

Tags: ios, launchimage

As launch nibs are iOS 8 onwards, what is the best way to create the required images showing a nav embedded tableview - would simulator screen shots be enough?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the simulator screen shot... paying attention not to have text visualized in it (because of the different localization of my products).

Bye
D.